# Changing Jet SQL IsNull to to SQL IsNull Function

Tags: t-sql, jet-sql

I have a query in MS Access that I am trying to change to SQL view

One of the select statement part is

```
IIf(IsNull([Book ID]),-1,[Book ID]) AS SubBookID
```

Unlike in Access T-SQL wants 2 parameters for the `IsNull` function.

What I need to do is something like

```
IIf(IsNull([Book ID],true),-1,[Book ID]) AS SubBookID
```

But we cannot use `true` like that cause T-SQL thinks that it is a column name

Comment: The equivalent is `IsNull([Book ID], -1) As SubBookID`. This will return either the `Book ID` if it's not NULL, or `-1` if it is; you don't need the `IIf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going to check if `[Book ID]` is null or not. If it is null then you are going to return `-1` else you are going to return the `[Book ID]`.

To achieve this you need to right it as:

```
ISNULL([Book ID],-1) AS SubBookID
```

As you see you do not need the `IIF` function anymore in this situation.

Read more about `ISNULL` in T-SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017